# Software to monitor traffic in Linux

Tags: linux, network-monitor

I'm looking for a qualitative software which counts the traffic of my internet line. I have an internet data stick and a limited traffic rate. So for instance I have 6000MB each month available. After I reach a user specified limit I want the system to warn me. If I exceed another limit the connection should be closed until the period which is set is over.

My requirements:

- The software should run under Linux
- Lightweight interface
- It should be possible to set up two limits (warning and block)
- Traffic management
- The software should warn me via E-Mail, if possible

On my Android smartphone, I'm able to set a limit for the mobile Internet. I can set a warning limit and a blocking limit. 
Is there a software available which can do this under Linux as well?

Comment: What you mean with "traffic management"? That you can block certain behaviours? Also are you targetting a whole network or just a single system?

Comment: Only to block or unblock traffic, if the limit is reached. Only the device for the mobile internet is the target.

Comment: This can be put together with [vnstat](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/330) and I believe a few people _have_, including a nice control panel - but I'm not finding it. Leaving it here in comments as breadcrumbs in hopes that it jogs someone else's memory. vnstat itself does this, you just need to wrap a couple cron jobs around it to trigger alerts (maybe piped through `mail`), and ultimately down the monitored interface if a halt is needed. Might just _write_ it later if I have time and can't find the implementation that exists.

Comment: What distro are you using? I assume you are going to want something that plays nice with whatever network configuration / connection manager software is the your default.

Comment: I use Edubuntu in version 12.04.

Comment: Wire shark may be useful for this.

Comment: Would you be able yo use Wine with this? If so, I have the perfect application...

Comment: Wine could be an alternative, as long as the software is able to run under Edubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NTM](http://webupd8.org/2011/10/network-traffic-monitor-ntm-for.html) (Network Traffic Monitor) is an application to use on computers with a limited Internet plan. It can display a complete report for received and transmitted network traffic and automatically disconnect after a certain period of time or after the traffic exceeds the value you set.
[Download Monitor](https://launchpad.net/download-monitor) displays monthly, daily and hourly amount of data transferred over the network and it can warn you using desktop notifications when you're about to exceed the usage quota, which you can set from its preferences. [install guide](http://webupd8.org/2012/07/monitor-network-usage-with-download.html)

[vnstat](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/330) is a widely used CLI network data usage counter. It can be easily scripted to suit your requirement.

NOTE: It is safe to use your service provides data counter as there will be a mismatch between the  ISP's and computer's counter. This mainly occurs due to the data packet loss during transmission. So it is better to use 95% of total as the cutoff value.